# IAP subscription with existing subscribers

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I'm developing the iOS app for a product that already have a large user base that pays through a subscription model on the product's website. In order to meet the 11.14 apple guideline, for new users we are going to implement the IAP subscription.

My question is, is there any approved mechanism to **IMPORT** the already **subscribed** user base? Existing subscribers will have to **PAY AGAIN** through the IAP subscription?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot import your existing customers into the IAP system.  In apps I've implemented that had a similar scenario, the users would either choose to subscribe via IAP or login with the credentials of their account that was already payed for via the website for the platform.

This is acceptable via the review guidelines.  What you cannot do is provide a link or form that would allow them to pay from the app without using IAP.